# How to execute different query based on returned value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of football matches defined as follow:

```
id |        datetime      | status | gameweek | round_id | home_team_id
 1   2019-03-31 00:00:00      1          29     12696          1243
 2   2019-03-31 00:00:00      1          29     12696          1248
 3   2019-03-31 00:00:00      1          29     12696          1242
 4   2019-03-31 00:00:00      1          29     12696          1246
 5   2019-03-31 00:00:00      1          29     12696          1244
 6   2019-03-31 00:00:00      1          29     12696          1247
 7   2019-03-31 20:30:00      1          29     12696          1241
 8   2019-03-31 00:00:00      1          29     12696          1249
 9   2019-03-31 00:00:00      1          29     12696          2981
 10  2019-03-31 00:00:00      1          29     12696          1259
```

I need to return all the `matches` which have as `gameweek` the next `gameweek` to the finished `matches` not all.

Some `rounds` doesn't have any `gameweek`, so in that case should be returned all the `matches` which have a `datetime` next to the finished `match`.

The query I wrote is this:

```
Select m.* from `match` m where round_id = 12696 and m.datetime = (SELECT COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN m2.status < 5 THEN m2.datetime END), MAX(m2.datetime)) FROM `match` m2 WHERE m2.round_id = m.round_id)
```

this return only 9 records, and I don't understand why, the only reason is that one record have the time too.

*What does finished `matches` mean?*

For `matches` ended or finished I mean that the status of each `match` is `5` or `3`. A status of `1` means that the `match` is scheduled, but hasn't played yet; `5` means `finished` and `3` canceled.

eg:

```
id |        datetime      | status | gameweek | round_id | home_team_id
 1   2019-03-20 00:00:00      5          29     12696          1243
 2   2019-03-20 00:00:00      5          29     12696          1248
 3   2019-03-20 00:00:00      5          29     12696          1242
 4   2019-03-31 00:00:00      1          29     12696          1246
 5   2019-03-31 00:00:00      1          29     12696          1244
 6   2019-03-31 00:00:00      1          29     12696          1247
 7   2019-03-31 20:30:00      1          29     12696          1241
 8   2019-03-31 00:00:00      1          29     12696          1249
 9   2019-03-31 00:00:00      1          29     12696          2981
 10  2019-03-31 00:00:00      1          29     12696          1259
```

as you can see the first three records are already played. In that case the query need to return all the `matches` (played and scheduled) because the `gameweek` 29 contains also other `matches` that hasn't played yet, so the expected result are all the 10 records.

**expected result**: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

Another important thing is that some `round` doesn't have any `gameweek`, so supposing this, we need to return the upcoming `matches`, eg:

```
id |        datetime      | status | gameweek | round_id | home_team_id
 1   2019-03-20 00:00:00      5        NULL     12696          1243
 2   2019-03-20 00:00:00      5        NULL     12696          1248
 3   2019-03-20 00:00:00      5        NULL     12696          1242
 4   2019-03-31 00:00:00      1        NULL     12696          1246
 5   2019-03-31 00:00:00      1        NULL     12696          1244
 6   2019-03-31 00:00:00      1        NULL     12696          1247
 7   2019-03-31 20:30:00      1        NULL     12696          1241
 8   2019-03-31 00:00:00      1        NULL     12696          1249
 9   2019-03-31 00:00:00      1        NULL     12696          2981
 10  2019-03-31 00:00:00      1        NULL     12696          1259
```

**expected result**: 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

(In the fiddle the record 7 is missing).

If there are no `gameweeks`, but all the `matches` are finished (status 5), then we need to return all the `matches` of the latest `datetime`, eg:

```
id |        datetime      | status | gameweek | round_id | home_team_id
 1   2019-03-20 00:00:00      5        NULL     12696          1243
 2   2019-03-20 00:00:00      5        NULL     12696          1248
 3   2019-03-20 00:00:00      5        NULL     12696          1242
 4   2019-03-31 00:00:00      5        NULL     12696          1246
 5   2019-03-31 00:00:00      5        NULL     12696          1244
 6   2019-03-31 00:00:00      5        NULL     12696          1247
 7   2019-03-31 20:30:00      5        NULL     12696          1241
 8   2019-03-31 00:00:00      5        NULL     12696          1249
 9   2019-04-05 00:00:00      5        NULL     12696          2981
 10  2019-04-05 00:00:00      5        NULL     12696          1259
```

**expected result**: 9, 10

```
id |        datetime      | status | gameweek | round_id | home_team_id
 1   2019-03-20 00:00:00      5        28     12696          1243
 2   2019-03-20 00:00:00      5        28     12696          1248
 3   2019-03-20 00:00:00      1        28     12696          1242
 4   2019-03-31 00:00:00      1        28     12696          1246
 5   2019-04-05 00:00:00      5        29     12696          1244
 6   2019-04-05 00:00:00      5        29     12696          1247
 7   2019-04-05 20:30:00      5        29     12696          1241
 8   2019-04-05 00:00:00      5        29     12696          1249
```

**Expected result:** 1,2,3,4,

I created a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8d2879ea4c8e631d6b59b59a6839b9e5) here which covers all the cases.

Comment: You should clarify your question: what does "next to the finished matches" mean? Can you give some examples? Aren't all matches finished if they are in the past and unfinished if they are in the future? Your query example can't possibly be right because there is no m2 defined. It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Dinu Hi, thanks for interesting in this question. I updated the question with some other details that I missed, sorry for this. If you have any other questions tell me, I will clarify too.

Comment: @sfarzoso: what would really help, I believe, would be to provide *a set of data* that typically represents your use case, and *the results that you accordingly expect*. If the requirements are too complex, maybe several sets of sample data/expected output.

Comment: @sfarzoso , I'm interested to know.. _"this return only 8 records, and I don't understand why"_ .. does those 8 records return the correct data?

Comment: Okay guys I updated the question making it more clearer, and I also added a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=71830cc9aa593b1e8d0977a55509e5c4 which cover all the cases, let me know if you have other questions about that problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feels like an unnecessarily complex query, but it does match the outputs stated above. Might be a good starting point.

```
with current_round as (
    select * 
    from match_case_1
    where round_id = 12696
)
select *
from current_round cr
where
    (
        not exists(select * from current_round where gameweek is null)
    )
    or 
    (
        exists(select * from current_round where status = 1) 
        and not exists(select * from current_round where gameweek is not null)
        and cr.status = 1    
    )
    or 
    (
        not exists(select * from current_round where status = 1)
        and not exists(select * from current_round where gameweek is not null)
        and cast(cr.`datetime` as date) = (
            select max(cast(`datetime` as date)) as `date`
            from current_round
            where status = 5 or status = 3
        )
    );
```

**EDIT**

DB Fiddle Queries on scenarios posted

1. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2f7NEPo72tUM7zLHBX2GXQ/0
2. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3ghG6zf7hv2SbACL9vtnJa/1
3. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q7DgtJRfDxyPA8bQheRncA/1
4. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tV7VhZg1Ywfx1YmnFMtZdh/1

Comment: Sure, but you might sacrifice a little clarity if you did that. First thing would be to get rid of the CTE, as that was added so that I could toggle between each cases quickly. Then you could combine a few of them due to repetition such as finding if there are any gameweek values or not.

Reducing query length like that though, you might lose clarity as to what each section describes

Comment: your query seems to cover almost all the case except one: db-fiddle.com/f/3ghG6zf7hv2SbACL9vtnJa/2 if you look there is another gameweek after 29, in this case need to be returned the records of gameweek 29 not all the other records, eg: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 your query return all..

Answer (score 1):

Given that it doesn't look like your matches will be changing super often, my advice would be to save yourself the headache and split up these queries in your application layer (if one exists)

Going from your examples, you can ask your DB a series of questions to get the results you want

*Is there a lowest gameweek that has unfinished matches for round 12696?*

```
SELECT MIN(gameweek) min_gameweek 
  FROM `match` 
 WHERE round_id = 12696
   AND gameweek IS NOT NULL
   AND status = 1
```

If yes.. *What are the matches for that gameweek?*

```
SELECT *
  FROM `match` 
 WHERE round_id = 12696
   AND gameweek = :min_gameweek
```

If no.. *(you may wish to try to find the maximum gameweek for finished matches in round 12696 here, and list all matches from that)*

If still no.. *What are the unfinished matches without a gameweek in round 12696?*

```
SELECT *
  FROM `match`
 WHERE round_id = 12696
   AND gameweek IS NULL
   AND status = 1
```

If none.. *Is their a latest datetime for a finished match without a gameweek in round 12696?*

```
SELECT MAX(`datetime`) latest_datetime
  FROM `match`
 WHERE round_id = 12696
   AND gameweek IS NULL
   AND status != 1
```

If yes.. *What are the finished matches without a gameweek in round 12696 that have this latest datetime?*

```
SELECT *
  FROM `match` 
 WHERE round_id = 12696
   AND `datetime` = :latest_datetime
```

**N.B.** This approach involves more queries, but is vastly more readable, debuggable, and flexible, and may even perform better than an attempt at one monster query

You could probably combine some of the queries above with adding too much opacity, but I'd still start by writing each step out and testing it

**I would also seriously suggest simplifying the whole process as follows**

- Store the current gameweek and max gameweek for each round in the round table (NULLed if there are no gameweeks for that round)
- Simply show all the matches for the current gameweek for the round in question
- When a match finishes (or at the end of the day/week), increment the current gameweek if all matches are finished and max is not yet reached

Comment: I like the way you organized the query, but your logic suppose to execute different queries before get the result, so how should I implement that solution? Specifically, I should check if each query return a result, and if not execute the next one?

Comment: Yes, I am proposing running each query separately, checking the result where necessary, and then running other queries based on the result. This could be done in the application layer of your project (if your project has one)

Comment: Isn't this solution more performance expensive against 1 query with multiple checking?

Comment: @sfarzoso Maybe, but not necessarily. One monster query will be quite complicated and may cause the engine to do extra work, checking and joining things that you could discount by doing the query in separate parts. The execution plan of a single complicated query would also be more likely to change as the table grows or changes.. which could result in an unexpected slow down. Even if separating the queries ends up being slower, I'd be very surprised if the slow down was significant

Answer (score 0):

just use 1 week future  filter

```
 select m.* from `match` m 
 WHERE DATE(datetime)>=date(now())
 and DATE(datetime) <= date_add(current_date, INTERVAL 1 week)       
 and m.status =1
```

Comment: If you check my update, you will see that your query doesn't cover all the cases, infact for the last case doesn't work, but for the others is right, could you fix that?

Comment: @sfarzoso how you know there no game weeks

Comment: 'cause the field `gameweek` is NULL, some competitions doesn't have the gameweeks

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM `match` m 
WHERE m.round_id = 48 AND 
      m.gameweek = (SELECT MAX(m1.gameweek) 
                    FROM `match` m1 
                    WHERE m1.round_id = m.round_id AND m1.status = 1
                   );
```

By this way, you will get the last played `gameweek` for each matches.